# Fatal Error after latest update to 5.60

Tags: wordpress

I have just upgraded to 5.60 and I am receiving this fatal error:

[14-Apr-2023 14:18:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Invalid field 'far_contact.is_deleted'
thrown in /home/xxx.xxx.com/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php on line 707

Is this a bug or can anybody help?

Regards, Ian.

Comment: Welcome to SE!   When do you get that error?  What version did you upgrade from?  Are there other errors in the logfile?